# Is it possible to have 2 different SSOs configured for a single AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, single-sign-on, idp

I have 2 customers that needs an access to the same environment. Each comes with his own different SSO tool (i.e. OneLogin or any other IDP). 
Is it possible to have 2 different SSOs configured for a single AWS account?
In general, is there a best practice for that (not necessarily to AWS but also to other platforms like GCP for example)?

Comment: I can not offer you much information regarding AWS as I don't have much experience with it, but for GCP there is a document [here](https://cloud.google.com/identity/solutions/enable-sso) which mentions how to enable SSO for your accounts and provides some insight on the use case and the advantages and disadvantages. Hope you find it useful

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Question is, if it's possible have connection from 2 different SSOs (IDPs) into the same account? Is this a familiar best practice to allow an MSP/Reseller to login into his customer's environments (the MSP from his own SSO, and the customer from his own SSO)?